# Who gets badges for Community Wiki posts?

Tags: support, badges, community-wiki

I just got a couple badges for [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102712/proof-the-fibonacci-numbers-are-not-a-polynomial/1102868#1102868) (made Community Wiki because I'm just expanding on a deleted answer, so I don't think I deserve the rep).

I'm the only person who ever touched this particular answer, so obviously in this case if there are badges to be handed out I must be the person who receives them. In general, though, a CW answer isn't going to be attributed to a single individual. So who is treated as its owner for badge purposes? The original poster? The person who contributed the most?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The original author still gets badges based on community posts.

From the official guide [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740)

---

Although the software makes some effort to show how various people contributed to a CW post, internally the post still has an "owner" (unless it has been disassociated). This connection  is used for notification and for issuing badges.